# Google App maker multiple transformers

Tags: google-app-maker

In App maker we can give model data sources to drop down. We have to apply mutiple filters in that binding but it is not working.

Format date is also not working can anyone suggest how to use transformers in that binding.

Comment: It is not clear, what you are asking about... transformers? projections? filters? Can you add code snippet that doesn't work?

Comment: @models.ECPMeetingMinutes.datasources.ECPMeetingMinutes.items..Topic#dintinct()#sort('asc')#formatDate('mm/dd/yyyy')

Comment: Is Topic a field of ECPMeetingMinutes model? If yes, what is type of the 'Topic' field?

Comment: Topic is a date field and i want distinct dates and the date should be formatted.

Comment: Topic is a date field, in the drop down this field must be formatted

Comment: I tried to play with your binding and it partly works (`#distinct()` and `#sort('asc')`), but `#formatDate('...')` doesn't work with projections. Looks like App Maker bug.